# Gridview using model binding not showing newly added items made by a Formview on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.5

I am current testing out model binding in ASP.NET 4.5.

I was testing a formview that accepts data from user and  displays the list of data in a GridView below after it was successfully saved. When the data is saved to the list the gridview remained empty.

I tried this example  by using an ObjectDataSource and it worked correct where by after the Postback when the form data is save the grid view shows all the items in the List.

Am I doing something that prevent from getting the desired behavior  when using the Model Binding? If so what is the correct way to get the desired behavior?

ASP.NET markup of the formview and the Grid view

```
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" ItemType="WebApplication35.Person" InsertMethod="SavePerson" SelectMethod="GetPeople">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />

                </HeaderTemplate>


                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    FirstName:

                    <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.FirstName %>' />
                    <br />
                    LastName:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="LastNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.LastName %>' />
                    <br />
                    Age:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AgeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.Age %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>

            </asp:FormView>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="WebApplication35.Person" SelectMethod="GetPeople"  PageSize="2">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    private static List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return people;
    }

    public void SavePerson(Person person)
    {
        people.Add(person);
    }


}
```

Person class

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridView stores last select data in viewstate and does not update it after postback.

So if you want to see updated result, right after insert, you need to rebind grid or disable viewstate for it

Comment: I forgot about the Viewstate. I decided to rebind the grid in the itemCreated event of the formview and it works perfectly.

Comment: @kenalex How did you accomplish the rebind? I'm stuck in the same situation.

Comment: nm. DataBind() worked perfectly, though I was unsure that it would.